# Serializing a Setter

Tags: haskell, serialization, haskell-lens

My program has a client and a server component that need to communicate. They each have a state that they mutate.
The mutation is done explicitly in the following way:

There a relation

```
class Diff a b where
    commit :: a -> b -> a
```

That says that type `b` can be considered a 'chunk' of type `a` and that you can modify objects of type `a` by 'committing' object of type `b` to them.

So you modify the state, those chunks get logged and transmitted to the client which also has an instance of the above relation, just for a different type `a`.

Now, here's the deal. My server's state is a record with many field. All of them can change since, you know, it's a state. That's what it does. This leaves me having to write a separate case in my 'chunk' type for each possible field so I can transmit them over the network. It would be lovely if I could somehow transmit any `state -> state` function, but I don't see that happening. The client shares the servers code, so it *does* know about the structure of my 'chunks', and the part where it has to interpret them to update it's own, local, state is something that I can manage.

What I was wondering is if I could maybe use lens here to automate the generation of update chunks. All my 'chunk' type is, after all, is a clumsy setter with a generic structure I can serialize.

What would be the best way to avoid repeating code here?

To give you a better idea of how my code currently looks, here's an example of how the server's state looks for a game of pong.

```
data State = State
           { playerPaddle :: Double
           , aiPaddle :: Double
           , ball :: Vec2 Double
           , ballV :: Vec2 Double } deriving Show

data Update = BallPos (Vec2 Double)
            | BallVel (Vec2 Double)
            | PlayerPos Double
            | AIPos Double

instance Diff State Update where
    commit s (BallPos p) = s { ball = p }
    commit s (BallVel p) = s { ballV = p }
    commit s (PlayerPos p) = s { playerPaddle = p }
    commit s (AIPos p) = s { aiPaddle = p }
```

Comment: With `lens` you could associate an `Update` with a particular lens, then use that within `commit`, but it's just moving the association elsewhere and adding a large dependency to your project.  It would look like `commit s update = updateToModifier update s` and `updateToModifier (BallPos p) = ball .~ p`; `updateToModifier (BallVel p) = ballV .~ p`; `updateToModifier (PlaerPos p) = playerPaddle .~ p`; `updateToModifier (AIPos p) = aiPaddle .~ p`.  This would make `commit` simple, but you would still have all the complexity with `updateToModifier`.

Comment: @bheklilr Yeah. I'm hoping there's a convenient solution.

Comment: If the client and server share code, you might be able to use the new `StaticPointers` extension (ghc dev branch only for now) to serialize `state -> state` functions.

Comment: @cdk I'm not comfortable with using an unreleased version of GHC, but that does look like it would be a great solution to my issue.